# No config.yaml file when installing Vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

So I downloaded this box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ncaro/boxes/php7-debian8-apache-nginx-mysql

I then go to my project folder and I execute the following commands:

```
vagrant init ncaro/php7-debian8-apache-nginx-mysql; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

But I dont see config.yaml in my directory. Why is that?

Best Regards

Comment: Why do you want to see a `config.yaml` ? Look through the docs the only thing needed is a Vagrantfile ... Config.yaml comes if you use Laravel, puphpet or other framework